# Vertical loop forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

So my buddy and I were playing roller coaster tycoon, and we were thinking about the physics behind a cart going around a loop. So we could think of the forces pretty easy for a loop on the x axis (think like ***O***->) but we had difficulty thinking of the forces of a cart going down from a vertical track such as a y axis (rotate above simple diagram by 90 degrees clockwise). We got that at the top of the loop the only force is $mv^2/r=mg$ but what about the force on the outside curve of the loop and the bottom of the loop (when oriented for y axis)?

Comment: Don't forget about the normal force between the cart and the track